# Populate TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6-beta5

I am new to Swift and I dont have experience in coding in Objective C. The problem I am facing is that, when I populate data from the class object into table view cells all the cells show the same data (the last recently accessed array object). Could someone help me with this ? 
Thanks.

```
    class TableViewController: UITableViewController{

    var urgentCenters:Array<UrgentCenterDetails> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadInfo()
        println("Number of entries: \(self.urgentCenters.count)")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //println("Number of rows \(urgentCenters.count)")
        return self.urgentCenters.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cellId = "cell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? UITableViewCell

        if nil==cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
        }

        if let ip = indexPath{
            cell!.textLabel.text = urgentCenters[indexPath.row].title
        }
        return cell       
    }

    func loadInfo(){

        // Append data to urgentCenters data
        var center = UrgentCenterDetails()
        var title:String 
        title = "Penn's Landing"
        center.setCenterDetails(title)
        urgentCenters.append(center)

        title = "Liberty Bell"
        center.setCenterDetails(title)
        urgentCenters.append(center)
    }
 }
```

Comment: everybody is new to swift `;-)` Where do you populate `urgentCenters`

Comment: in the loadInfo() function

Comment: the same code works if urgentCenters is an array of hard coded strings

Comment: There is no loop in `loadInfo` - How do you get multiple entries into the array?

Comment: using the append function

Comment: Your edit clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are only creating a single `UrgentCenterDetails` object and adding it to the array multiple times.  Because there is only a single object, when you change its properties you are affecting all elements of the array (because it is the same object in all elements).

You should have -

```
func loadInfo(){

    // Append data to urgentCenters data

    var title:String 
    title = "Penn's Landing"
    center.setCenterDetails(title)
    urgentCenters.append(center)

    center = UrgentCenterDetails()
    title = "Liberty Bell"
    center.setCenterDetails(title)
    urgentCenters.append(center)
}
```